# Forgot something doctor told me during consulation

Tags: politeness

I forgot something important that the doctor I saw for a consultation told me. Would it be rude of me to email his practice and ask him to tell me again what I have forgotten? I paid a lot of money for the consult, so I think I am entitled to a little bit of courtesy help. But I am not sure. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: Hi JRG! Looks like you're asking whether or not something is considered rude. Sadly, these types of questions aren't a good fit for this stack, since what's rude for one won't be for another, so they're primarily opinion based. See also our [help/on-topic]. We might be able to rephrase it to 'how to deal with this', but then I'd like to know why you think certain actions might be perceived as rude and/or are hesitant to 'just do it'. Also, where are you at? Culture does have a huge influence on what kind of approaches are considered rude or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be a relatively quick reminder/email, or an hour-long conversation/many pages of email?

If it's relatively quick, I see no issue at all. If it might take an amount of time similar to the amount of time taken by the original appointment, that could be an issue. But it's the doctor's job to tell you if you're asking for too much, so call in any case.

Comment: I ended up emailing him and he responded cheerfully. There was nothing to worry about.